# how to send a list of long to work with a rest controller

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

iam working on a api. i want to send a list of `Long` to find a project by an id.
This is the rest-controller:

```
@PostMapping("person/{id}/projects/")
    @JsonFormat (with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    public Person addProject(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<Long> project_id){
        Optional<Person> person = personRepo.findById(id);
        Person person1 = person.get();
        for(int i=0; i<project_id.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(project_id.get(i));
            Optional <Project> project = projectRepo.findById(project_id.get(i));
            person1.getProjectList().add(project.get());

        }
        System.out.println((person1.getProjectList()).toString());

        return personRepo.save(person1);
    }
```

And this is the request i send to the rest-controller

```
{
    "project_id": [1,2,3]
}
```

And iam getting this exception:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Long>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Long>` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

i`ve tried the same code as a PathVariable for the id, that worked. But this dosent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually send a json object here not a List

Send this in your post request instead.

```
 [1,2,3]
```

Your previous request could work if you had something like this

```java
public class X {
  @JsonFormat (with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
  private List<Long> project_id;
} 

@PostMapping("person/{id}/projects/")
public Person addProject(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody X x){..}
```